# How does Qwik build front-end projects with webpack?

Tags: webpack, qwik

Qwik is a React-like framework, I wonder how it works with webpack to build frontend projects? Today I tried to use it with webpack, but got the following error:

***Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@qwik-city-plan' in '/Users/liyunhua/study/qwik/qwik-webpack/node_modules/@builder.io/qwik-city'***

Please help to solve it, thank you